# React: _this.state is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote the following snippet:

```
export class Kurse extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {termineFreiburg: [
      {date: "21.02.2019", free: 10}, 
      {date: "02.05.2018", free: 0}, 
      {date: "13.03.2018", free: 10}, 
      {date: "04.07.2018", free: 12}, 
      {date: "05.08.2018", free: 12}
    ],
                termineKarlsruhe:[
      {date: "09.03.2019", free: 2},
      {date: "12.01.2018", free: 5}
    ]}
  }

  stadt = this.props.location.stadt;

  listItemsFreiburg = this.state.termineFreiburg.map((termin) =>
  <p><Link to={{pathname: "/bookCourse", datum: termin.date, stadt: this.props.location.stadt}}><Button>{termin.date}   Freie Plätze:  {(termin.free > 0)?termin.free:'ausgebucht'}</Button></Link></p>);

  listItemsKarlsruhe = this.state.termineKarlsruhe.map((termin) =>
  <p><Link to={{pathname: "/bookCourse", datum: termin.date, stadt: this.props.location.stadt}}><Button>{termin.date}   Freie Plätze:   </Button></Link></p>);

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h2>Wähle Deinen Wunschtermin für einen Kurs in {this.props.location.stadt}</h2>
        {(this.props.location.stadt === 'Freiburg') ? this.listItemsFreiburg : this.listItemsKarlsruhe}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default Kurse;
```

**Expected result:**

I expect that the dates will appear on the website (the app page).

**Actual result:**

I get "_this.state is not defined" with "constructor(props)" being highlighted.

As soon as I take the snippet with the dates out of the constructor all works fine!?

Any help? Or hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class field initializers like the one you're using to create `listItemsFreiburg` and such are executed **before** the code in the constructor (they're effectively inserted into the constructor at the beginning after the call to `super`). E.g., this:

```
class Example {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        this.answer = 42;
    }

    question = "Life, the Universe, and Everything";
}
```

is effectively this:

```
class Example {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        this.question = "Life, the Universe, and Everything";
        this.answer = 42;
    }
}
```

Notice the order. Details in [the class fields proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields).

That's why `state` is `undefined` as of when you're calling `map` to create `listItemsFreiburg` and the other one.

Either use a field initializer to create your state, or move your class field initializers into the constructor.

**However**, it seems odd to build those at construction time, given that they're based on state. I'd move them into `render` as locals, or at least update them when state changes.

Comment: I agree that it should be in render, I have not seen anyone map inside the constructor in react.

Answer (score 1):

`listItemsFreiburg`

`listItemsKarlsruhe`

`stadt = this.props.location.stadt;`

These need to be in the `render() { return() }` above the return statement.

like this with `const` before them.

```
render() {
 const listItemsFreiburg =  this.state.termineFreiburg.map((termin) =>
  <p><Link to={{pathname: "/bookCourse", datum: termin.date, stadt: this.props.location.stadt}}><Button>{termin.date}   Freie Plätze:  {(termin.free > 0)?termin.free:'ausgebucht'}</Button></Link></p>);
 const { stadt } = this.props.location;
 return (...) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bind **listItemsFreiburg** & **listItemsKarlsruhe** to **this** in the constructor like this:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state = {
      // Your data
   }

   this.listItemsFreiburg = this.listItemsFreiburg.bind(this);
   this.listItemsKarlsruhe = this.listItemsKarlsruhe.bind(this);

}
```

Comment: Great! Glad to help :D

Answer (score 0):

You don't need contructor(props) and super(props) just if you need to use this props in constructor.

You can't render just an object if the conditions is true.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    termineFreiburg: [
      { date: "21.02.2019", free: 10 },
      { date: "02.05.2018", free: 0 },
      { date: "13.03.2018", free: 10 },
      { date: "04.07.2018", free: 12 },
      { date: "05.08.2018", free: 12 }
    ],
    termineKarlsruhe: [
      { date: "09.03.2019", free: 2 },
      { date: "12.01.2018", free: 5 }
    ]
  };

  renderFreiburg = () => {
    return this.state.termineFreiburg.map(item => {
      return (
        <p>
          <span>{item.date} | </span>
          <span>{item.free}</span>
        </p>
      );
    });
  };
  render() {
    return <div>{true ? this.renderFreiburg() : null}</div>;
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

here is my example: https://codesandbox.io/s/q8kxr898l9